# Httpd service is not started with dlopen error in RHEL 8.4

Tags: apache, rhel, dlopen

I have upgraded the existing OS from RHEL 6.10 to RHEL 8.4. In 6.10 setup, the service is working fine. But in 8.4, when I try to start httpd service, the service is failed with the below error.

> /usr/xxxxx/xxx/apache/bin/httpd: symbol lookup error:
> /usr/xxxxx/xxx/apache/lib/libapr-1.so.0: undefined symbol: dlopen

Also, I tried installing the "libapr*" Package but got the below error,

> No match for argument: libapr1 Error: Unable to find a match: libapr1

Thanks in Advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some libraries in the "/lib64/" folder were not properly loading during the execution. Add the required libraries in LD_PRELOAD and export the same.

The above command helps me to overcome the issue.

Sometimes httpd service throws a "connection refused" error because of missing symbolic links. Adding those symbolic links will make the httpd service run.